# Unusual compiler errors when using <windows.h>

Tags: c++, windows, compiler-errors, include

I'm using gcc windows compiler (g++ -fpermissive -std=c++2a nuevotest.cpp) to compile this program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    cout << hex << 100 << '\n'; cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

And I'm getting this error messages regarding the windows headers (Windows SDK Version is 10.0.20348.0):

```
In file included from C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.20348.0/shared/minwindef.h:182,
                 from C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.20348.0/shared/windef.h:24,
                 from C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.20348.0/um/windows.h:171,
                 from nuevotest.cpp:4: C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.20348.0/um/winnt.h: In function 'void TpInitializeCallbackEnviron(PTP_CALLBACK_ENVIRON)': C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.20348.0/um/winnt.h:24122:33: error: expected primary-expression before ';' token 24122 |     CallbackEnviron->Pool = NULL;
      |                                 ^ C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.20348.0/um/winnt.h:24123:41: error: expected primary-expression before ';' token 24123 |     CallbackEnviron->CleanupGroup = NULL;
      |                                         ^ C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.20348.0/um/winnt.h:24124:55: error: expected primary-expression before ';' token 24124 |     CallbackEnviron->CleanupGroupCancelCallback = NULL;
      |                                                       ^ C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.20348.0/um/winnt.h:24125:36: error: expected primary-expression before ';' token 24125 |     CallbackEnviron->RaceDll = NULL;
      |                                    ^ C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.20348.0/um/winnt.h:24126:46: error: expected primary-expression before ';' token 24126 |     CallbackEnviron->ActivationContext = NULL;
      |                                              ^ C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.20348.0/um/winnt.h:24127:49: error: expected primary-expression before ';' token 24127 |     CallbackEnviron->FinalizationCallback = NULL;
      |                                                 ^ In file included from C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.20348.0/um/windows.h:203,
                 from nuevotest.cpp:4: C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.20348.0/um/winsock.h: At global scope: C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.20348.0/um/winsock.h:108:8: error: redefinition of 'struct timeval'   108 | struct timeval {
      |        ^~~~~~~ In file included from C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/time.h:262,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/10.2.0/ctime:42,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/locale_facets_nonio.h:39,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/10.2.0/locale:41,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/10.2.0/iomanip:43,
                 from nuevotest.cpp:3: C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/_timeval.h:10:8: note: previous definition of 'struct timeval'    10 | struct timeval
      |        ^~~~~~~ In file included from C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.20348.0/um/winscard.h:31,
                 from C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.20348.0/um/windows.h:208,
                 from nuevotest.cpp:4: C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.20348.0/um/winioctl.h: In function 'BOOLEAN DeviceDsmAddDataSetRange(PDEVICE_DSM_INPUT, DWORD, LONGLONG, DWORDLONG)': C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.20348.0/um/winioctl.h:4842:36: error: expected primary-expression before ';' token  4842 |     PDEVICE_DSM_RANGE Ranges = NULL;
      |                                    ^ In file included from C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.20348.0/um/windows.h:224,
                 from nuevotest.cpp:4: C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.20348.0/shared/stralign.h: In function 'WCHAR* ua_wcscpy_s(PUWSTR, size_t, PCUWSTR)': C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.20348.0/shared/stralign.h:450:106: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token   450 |         return (wcscpy_s( (PWSTR)Destination, DestinationSize, (PCWSTR)Source ) == 0 ? Destination : NULL);
```

Include directories:

```
C:/Users/jayok/Documents/asio-1.18.0/include
C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.20348.0/um
C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.20348.0/shared
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/10.2.0
C:/msys64/mingw32/include/c++/10.2.0/i686-w64-mingw32/bits
```

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include those errors in a code-formatted block, and not as a quote?

Comment: This looks like you've somehow managed to either undefine `NULL` or it was never defined.

Comment: If I redefine null I get "warning: "NULL" redefined"

Comment: Agreeing with @1201ProgramAlarm it's the 1st use of `NULL` in that file and in the include chain.  Check for any command line defines and/or any switches deprecating the use of `NULL`

Comment: What happens if you include the windows.h header first?

Comment: If I include windows.h before the other 2 headers, I get a lot, A LOT more errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some include files are loaded from `C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.20348.0/shared` and some from `C:/msys64/mingw64/include`.

So your mixing include locations that are not compatible with eachother.

You can't mix headers.
MinGW comes with its own headers.
You're not supposed to mix with other headers that define the same things.

You can also try compiler flag `-IC:/msys64/mingw64/include`, but you should really clean that up. For example check the `C_INCLUDE_PATH` environment variable.

If you want the latest headers get a recent MinGW-w64 like the standalone builds from https://winlibs.com/

Comment: If I used "-IC:/msys64/mingw64/include", the windows headers used would be the old ones. Also, I already CPP_INCLUDE_PATH to add all the needed include paths.

Comment: You can't mix headers. MinGW comes with its own headers. You're not supposed to mix with other headers that define the same things. If you want the latest headers get a recent MinGW-w64 like the standalone builds from https://winlibs.com

Comment: If you wrote this as an answer I could give you the bounty

Comment: @DarkoNaito_09 ok, I have updated my answer